# C program: implicit declaration of function and conflicting types

Tags: c, floating-point, division

Here's a function calculating the division of two numbers. All variables and functions are declared as float. However, the code below does not compile and the error message shows that "%f expects argument of type double, but argument has type int" and "implicit declaration of function 'div'" and "conflicting types for 'div'".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

float div(float a, float b);

int main() {
  float a = 5;
  float b = 8;
  printf("%f divided by %f is %f \n", a, b, div(a, b));
}

float div(float a, float b) { 
  assert(b != 0);
  return a / b;
}
```

Comment: There is a standard library function called `div`, and it does not return `float`. Though that shouldn't be a problem unless you `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: What compiler / version are you using and what compiler options?  It is no doubt failing for the reason Eric has suggested, but it would be unusual for a compiler to behave thus.  It would be helpful to be able to reproduce it, and for that the build details are required.

Answer (score 4):

The 2018 C standard discusses the standard library in clause 7. C 2018 7.1.3 1 says:

> … All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and `errno` are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.

In one of the following subclauses, 7.22.6.2, `div` is described as a function, and hence as an identifier with external linkage.

Therefore, it is reserved for use as the name of a standard library routine, and the behavior of a program that uses it for another purpose is not defined by the C standard.

Rename your function.